# Parsing encoded php object having a property containing html markup

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel-blade

I need to json encode a php object called 'contact' in my controller, pass it to my view and then parse it using javascript. One of the object properties contains HTML markup, which seems to cause a lot of issues. I have been running in to a lot of trouble successfully parsing the object.

I keep getting the following javascript error when calling `JSON.parse()`.

```
VM4464:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

What I tried:

PHP

```
$contact = htmlspecialchars(json_encode($contact), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Front end

```
var contact = JSON.parse("{{ $contact }}");
```

Comment: Am I to presume the entire string of `{{ $campaign }}` is replaced with the content of `$contact`? Or is there some other magic going on in there. Also, please provide a `print_r` or `var_dump` of `$contact` BEFORE you mangle it with htmlspecialchars (as `json_encode($contact)` alone should be doing all the work you need).

Comment: Also is this being called with ajax?

Comment: @IncredibleHat, please edited post, that should read $contact. Second, no I'm serving the encoded data from a Laravel controller.

Comment: @IncredibleHat, a simple json encode does not work, results in the same error.

Comment: Right... laravel. Someone who deals with that should step in, as the answer is probably pretty obvious, but dealing with that wrapper, makes it something I won't touch. Sorry.

Comment: You're encoding the entire JSON string with `htmlspecialchars` - I'm guessing that might be problematic? Have you tried to encode the object property itself beforehand and then `json_encode` the entire structure?

Comment: I have not, that seems more complex than it needs to be as more than one property contains markup and more than one object needs to be encoded. Isn't there a way to safely encode/decode the entire object? I've used the above method successfully in the past..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just yesterday I had the same problems, apparently it has something to do with blade escaping special character. I found the answers on this site,

try
`var contact = JSON.parse('{!! json_encode($contact) !!}');`

notice the use of {!! instead of {{, and try to experiment the usage of single/double quotes, or even without quotes, maybe?

Comment: Interesting. No JSON.parse is needed. No quotes, seemed to work! thanks for the help!